# Hierarchical forecast reconciliation in SAS

Tags: sas, time-series, hierarchical-data, forecasting

I hope I'm asking this in the right place:
I'm wanting to forecast a number of time-dependent events so that they are aggregate consistent. Could someone explain simply how to do this in SAS?

I'm working in SAS, and I've tried doing research on this, but for me, matrix algebra is really scary (I tried things like 'Game-Theoretically Optimal Reconciliation of Contemporaneous Hierarchical Time Series Forecasts'). I'm just a mortal and I don't know how to incorporate these kinds of formulae into my SAS coding.

The example for this question comes from 'sashelp.citiday'.
If I create a dataset, run some independent predictions based upon time, they don't add up to the total. I really want them to add up. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Code below:

```
data temp;
set sashelp.citiday;
format WeekDay $9.;
    /* Simplify some variables */
count1=round(SNYDJCM,1);
count2=round(SNYSECM,1);
count3=round(DFXWUK90,1);
    /* Create a 'Total' column */
total=sum (of count1-count3);
    /* create weekday */
day=datdif("1jan1988"d,date,'actual');
    if day=1 then weekday="Friday"; 
    if day=2 then weekday="Saturday"; 
    if day=3 then weekday="Sunday";
    if day=4 then weekday="Monday";
    if day=5 then weekday="Tuesday";
    if day=6 then weekday="Wednesday";
    if day=7 then weekday="Thursday";
        if weekday=. then do;   
            if round(day/7)=day/7 then weekday="Thursday"; 
            else if round((day-1)/7)=(day-1)/7 then weekday="Friday"; 
            else if round((day-2)/7)=(day-2)/7 then  weekday="Saturday"; 
            else if round((day-3)/7)=(day-3)/7 then  weekday="Sunday"; 
            else if round((day-4)/7)=(day-4)/7 then  weekday="Monday"; 
            else if round((day-5)/7)=(day-5)/7 then  weekday="Tuesday"; 
            else if round((day-6)/7)=(day-6)/7 then  weekday="Wednesday"; 
        end;
    /* Create Month */
Month=month(date);
keep date count1-count3 total day weekday month;
run;

%macro prediction(indata,outcome,predlab,outdata);
proc hpgenselect data=&indata.;
class weekday month;
model &outcome.=day weekday month weekday*month day*day /dist=nb ;
selection  method=backward  (choose=aic) hierarchy=single details=all ;
output out=&outdata. p=&predlab.;
run;
%mend prediction;

%prediction(temp,count1,pred1,forecast);
%prediction(forecast,count2,pred2,forecast);
%prediction(forecast,count3,pred3,forecast);
%prediction(forecast,total,predT,forecast);

data forecast;
set forecast;
sumpred=sum(of pred1-pred3);
diff=sumpred-predT;
run;
```

Comment: Not getting any love on this question - is there a way I can make it better/clearer? You'll get psychic/over-the-internet-hugs if you can help me understand it!